# How to add BiLSTM on top of BERT from Huggingface + CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 16.00 MiB

Tags: python, lstm, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I have the below code for a binary classification and it works fine but i would like to modify the nn.Sequential parameters and add an BiLSTM layer. I have the below code:

```
class BertClassifier(nn.Module):
 def __init__(self, freeze_bert=False):
  super(BertClassifier, self).__init__()
  # Specify hidden size of BERT, hidden size of our classifier, and number of labels
  D_in, H, D_out = 768, 50, 2

  # Instantiate BERT model
  self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')
  # Instantiate an one-layer feed-forward classifier
  self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(D_in, H),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(H, D_out))

  # Freeze the BERT model
  if freeze_bert:
   for param in self.bert.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

 def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
  # Feed input to BERT
  outputs = self.bert(input_ids=input_ids,attention_mask=attention_mask)
  # Extract the last hidden state of the token `[CLS]` for classification task
  last_hidden_state_cls = outputs[0][:, 0, :]
  # Feed input to classifier to compute logits
  logits = self.classifier(last_hidden_state_cls)

  return logits
```

I have tried to modify the sequential like this `self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.LSTM(D_in, H, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(H, D_out))` but then it throws the error `RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 2` on line `logits = self.classifier(last_hidden_state_cls)`. I found that I can use nn.ModuleDict instead of nn.Sequential and i made the below :

```
  self.classifier = nn.ModuleDict({
   'lstm': nn.LSTM(input_size=D_in, hidden_size=H,batch_first=True, bidirectional=True ),
   'linear': nn.Linear(in_features=H,out_features=D_out)})
```

But now I'm having issues computing the forward function with this. Can someone advice how i can properly modify the forward function?

Update: I also installed CUDA and now when I run the code it returns the error `CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 16.00 MiB`  and I tried to lower the batch size but that doesn't fix the problem. I also tried the below but didn't resolved either. Any advice, please?

```
import torch, gc
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Update with the code:

```
    MAX_LEN = 64
    # For fine-tuning BERT, the authors recommend a batch size of 16 or 32.
    batch_size = 32
    VALID_BATCH_SIZE = 4
    
    file1 = open('MH.txt', 'r')
    list_com = []
    list_label = []
    for line in file1:
     possible_labels = 'positive|negative'
     label = re.findall(possible_labels, line)
     line = re.sub(possible_labels, ' ', line)
     line = re.sub('\n', ' ', line)
     list_com.append(line)
     list_label.append(label[0])
    
    list_tuples = list(zip(list_com, list_label))
    file1.close()
    labels = ['positive', 'negative']
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_tuples, columns=['text', 'label'])
    df['label'] = df['label'].map({'positive': 1, 'negative': 0})
    for i in range(0,len(df['label'])):
     list_label[i] = df['label'][i]
    #print(df)
    #print(df['label'].value_counts())
    X = df.text.values
    y = df.label.values
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val =\
        train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=2020)
    
    def text_preprocessing(text):
     # Remove '@name'
     text = re.sub(r'(@.*?)[\s]', ' ', text)
     # Replace '&amp;' with '&'
     text = re.sub(r'&amp;', '&', text)
     # Remove trailing whitespace
     text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text).strip()
     return text
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased', do_lower_case=True)
    
    # Create a function to tokenize a set of texts
    def preprocessing_for_bert(data):
     input_ids = []
     attention_masks = []
    
     for sent in data:
      encoded_sent = tokenizer.encode_plus(
       text=text_preprocessing(sent),  # Preprocess sentence
       add_special_tokens=True,  # Add `[CLS]` and `[SEP]`
       max_length=MAX_LEN,  # Max length to truncate/pad
       pad_to_max_length=True,  # Pad sentence to max length
       # return_tensors='pt',           # Return PyTorch tensor
       return_attention_mask=True  # Return attention mask
      )
    
      # Add the outputs to the lists
      input_ids.append(encoded_sent.get('input_ids'))
      attention_masks.append(encoded_sent.get('attention_mask'))
    
     # Convert lists to tensors
     input_ids = torch.tensor(input_ids)
     attention_masks = torch.tensor(attention_masks)
    
     return input_ids, attention_masks
    
    train_inputs, train_masks = preprocessing_for_bert(X_train)
    val_inputs, val_masks = preprocessing_for_bert(X_val)
    
    # Convert other data types to torch.Tensor
    train_labels = torch.tensor(y_train)
    val_labels = torch.tensor(y_val)
    
    # Create the DataLoader for our training set
    train_data = TensorDataset(train_inputs, train_masks, train_labels)
    train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_data)
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)
    # Create the DataLoader for our validation set
    val_data = TensorDataset(val_inputs, val_masks, val_labels)
    val_sampler = SequentialSampler(val_data)
    val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_data, sampler=val_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)
    
    # Create the BertClassfier class
    class BertClassifier(nn.Module):
     """Bert Model for Classification Tasks."""
     def __init__(self, freeze_bert=False):
      """
      @param    bert: a BertModel object
      @param    classifier: a torch.nn.Module classifier
      @param    freeze_bert (bool): Set `False` to fine-tune the BERT model
      """
      super(BertClassifier, self).__init__()
      # Specify hidden size of BERT, hidden size of our classifier, and number of labels
      D_in, H, D_out = 768, 50, 2
    
      # Instantiate BERT model
      self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')
      # Instantiate an one-layer feed-forward classifier
      self.classifier = nn.ModuleDict({
       'lstm': nn.LSTM(input_size=D_in, hidden_size=H, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True),
       'linear': nn.Linear(in_features=H, out_features=D_out)})
    
      # Freeze the BERT model
      if freeze_bert:
       for param in self.bert.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False
    
     def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
      outputs = self.bert(input_ids=input_ids,attention_mask=attention_mask)
      sequence_output = outputs[0]
      sequence_output, _ = self.lstm(sequence_output)
      linear_output = self.linear(sequence_output[:, -1])

  return linear_output
    
    def initialize_model(epochs=4):
        # Instantiate Bert Classifier
        bert_classifier = BertClassifier(freeze_bert=False)
        print(bert_classifier)
        # Tell PyTorch to run the model on GPU
        bert_classifier.to(device)
        # Create the optimizer
        optimizer = AdamW(bert_classifier.parameters(), lr=5e-5)
        # Total number of training steps
        total_steps = len(train_dataloader) * epochs
        # Set up the learning rate scheduler
        scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer,num_warmup_steps=0,num_training_steps=total_steps)
        return bert_classifier, optimizer, scheduler
    
    # Specify loss function
    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    
    def set_seed(seed_value=42):
     """Set seed for reproducibility."""
     random.seed(seed_value)
     np.random.seed(seed_value)
     torch.manual_seed(seed_value)
     torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed_value)
    
    
    def train(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader=None, epochs=4, evaluation=False):
     """Train the BertClassifier model."""
     # Start training loop
     print("Start training...\n")
     for epoch_i in range(epochs):
      # Print the header of the result table
      print(f"{'Epoch':^7} | {'Batch':^7} | {'Train Loss':^12} | {'Val Loss':^10} | {'Val Acc':^9} | {'Elapsed':^9}")
      print("-" * 70)
      # Measure the elapsed time of each epoch
      t0_epoch, t0_batch = time.time(), time.time()
      # Reset tracking variables at the beginning of each epoch
      total_loss, batch_loss, batch_counts = 0, 0, 0
      # Put the model into the training mode
      model.train()
      # For each batch of training data...
      for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
       batch_counts += 1
       # Load batch to GPU
       b_input_ids, b_attn_mask, b_labels = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
       # Zero out any previously calculated gradients
       model.zero_grad()
       # Perform a forward pass. This will return logits.
       logits = model(b_input_ids, b_attn_mask)
       # Compute loss and accumulate the loss values
       loss = loss_fn(logits, b_labels)
       batch_loss += loss.item()
       total_loss += loss.item()
       # Perform a backward pass to calculate gradients
       loss.backward()
       # Clip the norm of the gradients to 1.0 to prevent "exploding gradients"
       torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
       # Update parameters and the learning rate
       optimizer.step()
       scheduler.step()
       # Print the loss values and time elapsed for every 20 batches
       if (step % 20 == 0 and step != 0) or (step == len(train_dataloader) - 1):
        # Calculate time elapsed for 20 batches
        time_elapsed = time.time() - t0_batch
        # Print training results
        print(
         f"{epoch_i + 1:^7} | {step:^7} | {batch_loss / batch_counts:^12.6f} | {'-':^10} | {'-':^9} | {time_elapsed:^9.2f}")
        # Reset batch tracking variables
        batch_loss, batch_counts = 0, 0
        t0_batch = time.time()
      # Calculate the average loss over the entire training data
      avg_train_loss = total_loss / len(train_dataloader)
    
      print("-" * 70)
      #Evaluation
      if evaluation == True:
       # After the completion of each training epoch, measure the model's performance
       # on our validation set.
       val_loss, val_accuracy = evaluate(model, val_dataloader)
    
       # Print performance over the entire training data
       time_elapsed = time.time() - t0_epoch
    
       print(
        f"{epoch_i + 1:^7} | {'-':^7} | {avg_train_loss:^12.6f} | {val_loss:^10.6f} | {val_accuracy:^9.2f} | {time_elapsed:^9.2f}")
       print("-" * 70)
      print("\n")
    
     print("Training complete!")
    
    
    def evaluate(model, val_dataloader):
     """After the completion of each training epoch, measure the model's performance
     on our validation set.
     """
     # Put the model into the evaluation mode. The dropout layers are disabled during
     # the test time.
     model.eval()
    
     # Tracking variables
     val_accuracy = []
     val_loss = []
    
     # For each batch in our validation set...
     for batch in val_dataloader:
      # Load batch to GPU
      b_input_ids, b_attn_mask, b_labels = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
    
      # Compute logits
      with torch.no_grad():
       logits = model(b_input_ids, b_attn_mask)
    
      # Compute loss
      loss = loss_fn(logits, b_labels)
      val_loss.append(loss.item())
    
      # Get the predictions
      preds = torch.argmax(logits, dim=1).flatten()
    
      # Calculate the accuracy rate
      accuracy = (preds == b_labels).cpu().numpy().mean() * 100
      val_accuracy.append(accuracy)
    
     # Compute the average accuracy and loss over the validation set.
     val_loss = np.mean(val_loss)
     val_accuracy = np.mean(val_accuracy)
    
     return val_loss, val_accuracy
    
    def accuracy(probs, y_true):
     """
     - Print AUC and accuracy on the test set
     @params    probs (np.array): an array of predicted probabilities with shape (len(y_true), 2)
     @params    y_true (np.array): an array of the true values with shape (len(y_true),)
    
    
     fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(y_true, preds)
     roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
     print(f'AUC: {roc_auc:.4f}')
    """
     preds = probs[:, 1]
     # Get accuracy over the test set
     y_pred = np.where(preds >= 0.5, 1, 0)
     accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
     print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%')
    
    def bert_predict(model, test_dataloader):
     """Perform a forward pass on the trained BERT model to predict probabilities on the test set."""
     # Put the model into the evaluation mode. The dropout layers are disabled during the test time.
     model.eval()
     all_logits = []
     # For each batch in our test set...
     for batch in test_dataloader:
      # Load batch to GPU
      b_input_ids, b_attn_mask = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)[:2]
    
      # Compute logits
      with torch.no_grad():
       logits = model(b_input_ids, b_attn_mask)
      all_logits.append(logits)
    
     # Concatenate logits from each batch
     all_logits = torch.cat(all_logits, dim=0)
     # Apply softmax to calculate probabilities
     probs = F.softmax(all_logits, dim=1).cpu().numpy()
    
     return probs
    
    set_seed(42)    # Set seed for reproducibility
    bert_classifier, optimizer, scheduler = initialize_model(epochs=3)
    # start training
    train(bert_classifier, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, epochs=3, evaluation=True)
    # Compute predicted probabilities on the test set
    probs = bert_predict(bert_classifier, val_dataloader)
    # Evaluate the Bert classifier
    accuracy(probs, y_val)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by `But now I'm having issues computing the forward function with this.`? CUDA does not change the logic o your model, it just speeds it up by executing it on GPU. That you run out of memory just means that the model and the data you use are too big. Try to reduce the batch size to 1 and see what happens.

Comment: So I changed the nn.Sequential part with the nn.ModuleDict above but now i'm having issues computing the forward functions properly because i receive the error `forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` . (that's when i run on CPU). Then i found that i didn't had CUDA installed and I  installed it (pytorch+cuda) and i received the out of memory error. I already tried to reduce the batch size to 16, 4 and also 1 but it still throws the same error but with bigger MiB... .

Comment: Let's ignore the cuda error for now. Please post the code that is causing the forward error message and post the full error stacktrace. The code you are currently showing can not produce such an error message.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full code and this is the error stacktrace :
 `File "bert.py", line 306, in <module>
    train(bert_classifier, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, epochs=3, evaluation=True)
  File "bert.py", line 183, in train
    logits = model(b_input_ids, b_attn_mask)
  File "bert.py", line 132, in forward
    logits = self.classifier(last_hidden_state_cls)
  File "\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: The error is caused by this line `logits = self.classifier(last_hidden_state_cls)`. The `ModuleDict` does not call the `forward` methods of its elements. You maybe want to use `nn.Sequential ` or call them one after another `classifier['lstm'](last_hidden_state_cls)` and `classifier['linear'](the lstm output)`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have tried with `self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.LSTM(D_in, H, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True),nn.Linear(H, D_out))` but i  receive the error `input must have 3 dimensions, got 2` on the same line as before (logits =...)

Comment: This tells you that this line `last_hidden_state_cls = outputs[0][:, 0, :]` is turning your tensor in a 2 dimensional input but the lstm expects a 3 dimensional input.

Comment: I reshaped it like this `last_hidden_state_cls=last_hidden_state_cls.view(batch_size,1,768)` and how it has `torch.Size([32, 1, 768])` ( before it had `torch.Size([32, 768])` and it passes the LSTM but now i have another error when it reaches to the nn.Linear : `linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple`  on this line `logits = self.classifier(last_hidden_state_cls)`. Any idea what can i do to fix this?

Comment: The [lstm returns a tuple](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html). You are probably interested only in the first value of the tuple and you need to wrap it into class to select only the first one.

Comment: I tried to change the nn.sequence into `self.lstm = nn.LSTM(D_in, H, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
  self.linear = nn.Linear(H , D_out)` and after i reshaped the last_hidden_state_cls, i did `lstm_output = self.lstm(last_hidden_state_cls)
  linear_output = self.linear(lstm_output[0])` and receive the error `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x100 and 50x2)`

Comment: I've modified `self.linear = nn.Linear(H , D_out)` with `self.linear = nn.Linear(H*2 , D_out)` and resolved the mat1 and mat2 error but now i get `Expected target size (32, 2), got torch.Size([32])` on this line `loss = loss_fn(logits, b_labels)` .... Should i reshape the linear_output ?

Comment: So i reshaped the linear output `linear_output =linear_output.view(batch_size,2)` and now the training starts but during the training, batch 720 in first epoch, it stopped and returned the error `shape '[32, 1, 768]' is invalid for input of size 21504` on line `last_hidden_state_cls=last_hidden_state_cls.view(batch_size,1,768)` . Any idea how i can fix this...?

Comment: It is strange that it throws the error during the training... Is there any way i can completely change the forward function and make it work as expected? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please, like already mentioned before. Updated your question with the most recent code and post the full error stacktrace with your question (not as a comment). The last line of the error isn't helpful at all and it is also cumbersome to put the current version of your code together from ll the comments.

Comment: I've managed to fix the problem, and updated the code, thank you for the help.